# Render a loop in Timber (twig for Wordpress)

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, query-posts

I would like to render this loop in Timber.

```
$query = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'lexique','posts_per_page' => -1));

$by_letter = array();
while( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
  global $post;
  $letter = substr($post->post_name, 0, 1);
  if ( ! isset($by_letter[$letter]) ) $by_letter[$letter] = array();
  $by_letter[$letter][] = $post;
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

So attach this loop with timber

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
Timber::render('lexique.twig', $context);
```

But I don't have any idea to do this.

Comment: What is Timber? Please edit your question to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

@Xroad, here's the simplest way. Things can get a bit more complicated depending on the specifics, but this is the most straightforward way:

```
$query = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'lexique','posts_per_page' => -1));

$by_letter = array();
while( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
  global $post;
  $letter = substr($post->post_name, 0, 1);
  if ( ! isset($by_letter[$letter]) ) $by_letter[$letter] = array();
  $by_letter[$letter][] = $post;
}

$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['posts_by_letter'] = $by_letter;
Timber::render('lexique.twig', $context);
```

**lexique.twig**

```
{% for letter in posts_by_letter %}
  {% for post in letter %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.link }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```